# Error : HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

After adding the context file i get this error : Statut 404 ..
my web file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>CRUDWebAppMavenized</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:log4j.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3J0vA.jpg)

I don't know where is exactly the problem ! the 'student.jsp' page there is inside the wepapp folder.

Comment: Google how to read a stack trace. At least google what a stack trace is so you know WHERE to look for the problem. Also don't attach images, post the relevant code here, and all relevant error messages

Comment: And sometimes i get this error : HTTP Status 404 -  Why ??

Comment: Because something was not found

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

You are probably missing the ContextLoadListener, which picks up your Spring configuration files. If this doesn't solve your issue, edit your question to include the contents of your web.xml file.

Comment: DONE ! after doing that i get the 404 error message.

Comment: That is because your application isn't able to find the webpage you're looking for. Either you do not have it in your application, or, it is setup incorrectly. Post a picture of your file structure, and also what link you're trying to access, and maybe I could help.

Comment: i'v added the structure picture ! please check !